# How to check in a list of numbers if three of them will add up to 15?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to set up a conditional if statement that returns True if the following is true.

list1 = [1, 5, 8, 2, 9]
In this case, returns true since 5 + 8 + 2 = 15.

list2 = [2, 8, 4, 1, 7]
In this case, returns false 3 number combination adds up to 15.

Comment: and what have you tried? where did you get stuck?

Comment: It depends the length of list. It may be difficult if you need deal with a long list.

Answer (score 2):

```
def find_two_sum(first_number, idx, arr, ans):
    target_sum = 15-first_number
    left = idx+1
    right = len(arr)-1
    while left < right:
        if arr[left] + arr[right] == target_sum:
            # find two numbers with sum 15-first_number
            return True
        elif arr[left] + arr[right] < target_sum:
            left += 1
        
        else:
            right -= 1

    return False


def is_sum_fifteen(nums):
    
    nums.sort()
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if find_two_sum(nums[i],i, nums):
            # if found any three numbers with sum 15 return True
            return True

    return False
```

This code will return you the answer in O(n^2) time complexity.
(This is the best silution assuming:

1. The list is going to be very large
2. The list is not sorted.)